# Laravel 4 timestamp format

Tags: laravel, date, timestamp

I'm using Laravel 4 and I want to display created_at. It is timestamp.
I display it in this way - it should be in this format -`Y.m.d / h:i`

but it shows wrong result. Column created_at in database has value -

`2016-05-18 00:00:00`

but when I display it in this way it shows:

`2016.05.18 / 12:00`

```html
@if($data->created_at !== '0000-00-00 00:00:00') 
{{date('Y.m.d / h:i', strtotime($data->created_at)) }}
@endif
```

Comment: `Y.m.d / h:i` should be `Y.m.d / H:i` with a capital `H` for 24 hour times. You might also benefit from using the [Date mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#date-mutators) built into Laravel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Y-m-d H:i:s` is ISO format to store date time value and Laravel is always using it AFAIK. But it should not be problem if you are using Eloquent then `created_at` is `Carbon` datetime and you can format it by calling `format()` method. `{{ $data->created_at->format('Y.m.d / H:i'); }}`

Comment: Yes, I'm using Laravel timestamps, and how should I check if there is data in created_at field - I mean if it is not NULL and it is not with that value -'0000-00-00 00:00:00' ? Is this good way for that-> `@if($data->created_at !== '0000-00-00 00:00:00' && $data->created_at ) `